# Connectors confusion

Tags: grammatical-roles

Linguists shy away from calling connectors adverbs and instead say they form a separate class. Unfortunately, there seems to be no universally agreed name for this new class: some say “connectors”, some say “logical connectors”, some say “coherence markers”, some say “conjuncts”"Phrasal transitions""discourse markers" etc . Many people, including teachers, have been confused by all this. Can someone Provide a definitive reason for this and their grammatical function besides connecting.

Comment: If no group of acknowledged experts in the field can agree, how could anybody on this site provide something better?

Comment: Can you Post three or four example sentences?

Comment: Sure Robbie. Examples He wants to be a singer. To achieve this/for this,  he is working very hard. (is 'to achieve this'/for this 'a connector/conjunctive adverb or not modifying the complete clause the way a sentence adverb functions? Thanks

Comment: In that case, back to Jason, or can you post several more examples showing the range, rather than a single application of that class… particularly if there is clearly a "grammatical function besides connecting." Personally, I'd rate "To achieve this/for this…" as an elaborate conjunction.

Comment: Dear Robbie, Conjunction is a separate and well defined class of connectors in the parts of speech. The confusion is with other types which include conjunctive adverbs that have prepositiona/infinitivel phrases also referred in their class by certain sections of linguists.